# How can I make input fields line up next to the middle of the labels?

Tags: html, css

Here's an example of the problem I am facing:
https://jsfiddle.net/v10un11s/1/

This is my HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="component">
    <div>
      <label for="test1" id="short-label">Short label: </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="test1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="component">
    <div>
      <label for="test2" id="long-label">This is my very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long label: </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="test2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My css:
.

```
component > div:first-child {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.component > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This results in the input field lining up to the right of the labels. This is what I want, however, it lines at the end of the line of a very long label.

What I really want is that the input field line to the right AND to the relative middle of the label.

So in the JS Fiddle example above, I would want the input field to line up to the right of the third line of the long label.

I've been playing around with margins, paddings, line-height, etc etc, and I've not been able to figure out the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one line of CSS should do the trick!

```
.component > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Just remember, this works both ways - so if your input is taller than your label, the label will center to the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Flexbox` and set `align-items: center` on `.component`

```css
.component {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.component > div:first-child {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="component">
    <div>
      <label for="test1" id="short-label">Short label:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="test1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="component">
    <div>
      <label for="test2" id="long-label">This is my very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long label:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="test2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```